# Use of special keys in opengl makes my computer really slow

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, rotation, glut

I write an opengl code that draws some objects, lights and textures on the objects. Special keys such as arrows rotate my texture mapped objects. But if I continue rotating them for ~10 seconds I even can not close the opengl window. I do not post my code, it is a bit long and I do not have any idea which part of it slows it down.

Comment: What function call are you using to read keypresses?

Comment: glutSpecialFunc calls my arrow handler function.
In arrow handler:
if(GLUT_KEY_UP)
{//rotate
glutPostRedisplay();}
if(GLUT_KEY_DOWN
....)
...... so on.

Comment: Figure out which part of it slows it down first, then post a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer in the comments section I think I see what is going on.

> glutSpecialFunc calls my arrow handler function. In arrow handler:
>   if(GLUT_KEY_UP) {//rotate glutPostRedisplay();} if(GLUT_KEY_DOWN ....)
>   ...... so on

That is not the right way to handle keyboard events in your glut program.  You are actually causing the amount of work done in your rendering loop to vary based on the number of keypresses the user makes.

Instead of posting the redisplay in response to a keystroke, you should instead have a main drawing loop that continues to redraw the scene independent of the keyboard activity.  You will also need to have state variables for location (x, y, z), and angles for look-at rotation.  The drawing routine simple draws your scene using the x, y, z, and rotation information in these state variables.

Then for your keyboard handling you simply change these state variables as appropriate in response to the keystrokes you support in your program.  The main drawing loop will automatically respond to these changes as it is running freely asynchronously with the keyboard handler.

Comment: If you are familiar with Python and Pyglet, here is a good example of a simple opengl program that uses the technique I am talking about: https://github.com/fogleman/Minecraft/blob/master/main.py

Comment: It helped some but now it starts after ~20 seconds. Is there any limited stack like thing in opengl? maybe it is being filled?